# Перебор списка статуса url

Tags: python, http, for, request

Есть код:

```
import urllib3
from collections import Counter

filename = "links.json"
a = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()


def links_chek():
    for i, url in enumerate(content, 1):
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        resp = http.request('GET', url)
        if resp.status == 404:
            print(f'Ссылка {i} не работает')
        else:
            print(f'Ссылка {i} работает')
        a.append(resp.status)
        wok = Counter(a)

    print('Не работает: ' + str(wok[404]) + ' ссылки')
    print('Работает: ' + str(wok[200]) + ' ссылки')
    print(f'Всего проверенно: {len(content)} ссылок')
    print(f'Имя файла с ссылками: {filename}')


links_chek()
```

На выходе получаю:

```
Ссылка 1 не работает
Ссылка 2 работает
Ссылка 3 работает
Ссылка 4 работает
Ссылка 5 не работает
Ссылка 6 не работает
Ссылка 7 работает
Не работает: 3 ссылки
Работает: 4 ссылки
Всего проверенно: 7 ссылок
Имя файла с ссылками: links.json
```

Файл "links.json" содержит:

```
https://***.by/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/hren/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/soevyj-sous/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/gorchica-adzhika/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/ketchup-sous-tomatnyj/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/majonez-sous-majoneznyj/
https://***.by/catalog/bakaleya/ketchup-majonez-sousy-gorchica-hren/sous-fruktovyj-yagodnyj/
```

Почему так происходит?
Все ссылки рабочие.
Заметил, что чем больше ссылок, тем ошибочней результат, может обход ссылок идет слишком быстро?
Иногда статус может поменятся и не понимаю как это работает.
Куда копать?

Comment: а не проще использовать `requests.get()`??

Comment: <Response [404]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [404]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [404]>
<Response [200]>
Почти такие же результаты и я про это и говорю, почему статус от каждой проверки меняться?

Comment: сколько времени вы ожидаете ответ, и за сколько времени он выдается при запуске проверки вручную из cmd, например?

Comment: что за ресурс? может стоять ддос защита

Comment: Время ответа не знаю, проверил через первый скрипт который нашел и получил это:1.8999562598764898e-08
Через cmd не запускал, имеет смысл?
Сейчас почти все хостеры защищают сайты от ддоса, так что да, я думаю сам хостер не пускает. 
Я уже думаю, открывать каждую ссылку через браузер и парсить ответ? Может можно проще?

Comment: https://***.by че за секретность? или вы реально не хотите чтоб вам не помогли

Comment: Так вы сохраняйте в файлы содержание страниц, когда получаете 404. И посмотрите, что там. Не исключаю, что там страница требует капчу или ещё что-то такое. Проще взять да посмотреть, что там, чем вот так гадать.

Comment: https://green-dostavka.by? Если да, все ответы <Response [200]> по вашему списку

Comment: Все верно, Сергей, я просто хочу разобраться в вопросе, а не лишний раз светить домен. Так как вы это сделали, что у вас все url ответили 200?

Comment: Ваш код у меня работает все ответы 200. Значит вас частично блокируют